# Jquery draggable cloned divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, clone, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a problem with my webpage implementation with **JQuery**. I know it will be difficult to understand what I am trying to do but I will try to make it the most clear I can (although my english is not really good).

I have a webpage whith a **div that is possible to drag** inside a "containment-wrapper", and I have implemented that **when you drag it, you get a clone** (a copy) of that *main* div and then you can drag this cloned div around the screen (inside the "containment-wrapper"). Every time you drag the *main* div another cloned div is created. It works perfectly.

The code:

```
$(".tool").draggable({
        containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        helper: 'clone',
        stop: function(event, ui) {
                 if($num==null) $num=0; //treat a number for the id of the next cloned div
                 else $num++;
                 $(ui.helper).clone(true).attr("id",$(this).attr("id")+$num).removeClass('tool ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging ui-widget-content').addClass('element ui-widget-content').appendTo('#containment-wrapper');
            }
    });
```

**The problem** is that I have to implement that when you load that webpage, **the user have saved his anterior div's situation in the server**: the position of all the cloned div's (I have saved the id of the *main* div, and the position - top and left).

So **I am trying to implement a code**, executed just when the page is loaded, **that create and situate the cloned divs that the user have saved**, to the screen (inside the "containment-wrapper").

I got it with this code (I have the values: **$id** - id of the *main* div, **$left** and **$top** - position of the div that I have to create):

```
        var $obj = $("#"+$id); //get the main div
        if($num==null) $num=0; //treat a number for the id of the next cloned div
        else $num++;

        $obj.clone(true).attr("id",$id+"_"+$num).removeClass('ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging ui-widget-content').addClass('ui-widget-content').appendTo('#containment-wrapper').css( { "position": "absolute", "left":$left + "px", "top":$top + "px" } );
```

It creates the cloned div's where I want, but my big problem is that **when I try to drag that cloned div's with the mouse, inside of being dragged that div, it start to be dragged the *main* div** (the one from which I create the cloned divs) and another cloned div is created. So it is impossible to drag that cloned div that my code has created.

I hope it is possible to understand all my situation and my problem... Any idea of how could I solve it?

I also tried to do something like this (with it, I was thinking to treat the position in the draggable event function):

```
        var $obj = $("#"+$id);
        $obj.trigger("mousedown.draggable", [ev]);
        ev.stopPropagation();
```

But when I debug it with firebug (firefox pluggin), I see that the event draggable is never executed.

Thank you very very much for your time,

Aleix

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your english is fine! Is it possible for you to provide a condensed example of your problem on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: why don't you just allow the "main div" to be dragged instead and leave the clone behind. Swap the id and add the event listener to the clone then.

Comment: @Adrew: I am looking how it works "jsfiddle.net" because I didn't knew about it and I have never used it. When I get it, I'll tell you ;) Thank you!
 // 
@Yman: Thank you for your idea. I understand it but I think that if I have to create more than one cloned div from the main one, then I will have the same problem... Anyway I can try it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it!** The code was OK, the only problem was the call to the *initialize()* function that was the responsible to create the cloned divs: I was calling this function with this code line (inside the JavaScript code):

```
    window.onload = initialize;
```

If I **delete this line and I call the `initialize()` function from the `$(document).ready` function**, then everything works OK!! :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        [...]
        initialize();
        });
```

I realised about it, trying to simplify the code in *jsfiddle.net*. So, stupid error but I am so so happy to have solved it finally :)

Thank you very very much for your comments.